# Edit JSON object - looking for better functional approch

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a JSON object with setting, something similar to this:

```
var settings = {
  tab1: {
    active: true,
    selectOrder: 1,
    selected: false
  },
  tab2: {
    active: true,
    selectOrder: 2,
    selected: false
  },
  tab3: {
    active: false,
    selectOrder: 0,
    selected: false
  }
};
```

Now, my goal is to set the 'selected' property to be  'true' for the active element with the lowest 'selectedOrder'. In this example I should set 'selected' for 'tab1' element ('tab3' have selectedOrder of 0 but is not active).

The reason behind it is to select the first active tab according to its priority (selectOrder).

My solution was:

```
function selectFirstActiveTab(visibilitySettings) {
  var selected = 1000;
  var answer = jQuery.extend({}, visibilitySettings);
  Object.keys(answer).forEach((key) => {
    if (answer[key].active && answer[key].selectOrder <= selected) {
      selected = answer[key].selectOrder;
    }
  });

  Object.keys(answer).forEach((key) => {
    answer[key].selected = (answer[key].selectOrder === selected) ? true : false;
  });
  return answer;
};
```

While this solution is working, it seems like a bad one.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better "functional programming" approach for that? (using map/reduce etc., for example)
2. I feel that my settings object is not structured well. Maybe I should choose an array of objects instead of this JSON? The reason for choosing a JSON like this one was for simpler binding to my template (something like "{{settins.tab1.selected}}" - simpler that looking for it inside my html). What should be the better approach here?

[Here is the complete example in JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cacazimeje/edit?js,console)

Comment: You can keep the minimum value and the ref to the obj, so you only need to loop once.

Comment: Yes, the two iterations were because at first place I updated the selected=false as well.

Comment: _using map/reduce.._ You **cannot** use Array's `map`/`reduce` methods since you have object, not array. I would suggest you to use JS utitlity lib such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#objects).

Comment: @hindmost: map/reduce is not limited to arrays, it's a generic approach to traversables.

Comment: @Bergi But the OP's object is not traversable nor array-like object. It's just plain object.

Comment: @hindmost: Objects (key-value maps) are traversable

Comment: @Bergi Ok. They're traversable, but do they have `map`/`reduce` methods defined? defined by default, like in arrays?

Comment: @hindmost: Of course they have not, but that doesn't prevent us from using a functional map/reduce approach on them.

Comment: @Bergi Ofcourse, we can. However it's much easier to use ready methods like in arrays or Underscore, than write custom ones from scratch, imho.

Comment: @hindmost: No need for custom methods. `_.map` and `_.reduce` from underscore work right away on objects :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For map and reduce on `Object`, you can use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
function selectFirstActiveTab(visibilitySettings) {
  // Clone input, with selected set to false.
  var answer = _.mapObject(visibilitySettings, (item, key) => {
    return {active: item.active, selectOrder: item.selectOrder, selected: false};
  });

  // Find the min among all value.
  var minObj = _.reduce(answer, (min, item) => {
    return (item.active && item.selectOrder < min.selectOrder) ? item : min;
  }, {active: true, selectOrder: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER});

  // Set min to selected.
  minObj.selected = true;
  return answer;
};
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/bamorunapu/1/edit?js,console)

or vanilla javascript:

```
function selectFirstActiveTab(visibilitySettings) {
  var keys = Object.keys(visibilitySettings);

  // Create a cloned obj, like map
  var answer = {};
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    var cloneTarget = visibilitySettings[key];
    answer[key] = {
      active: cloneTarget.active,
      selectOrder: cloneTarget.selectOrder,
      selected: false
    };
  });

  // Convert key => value map to an array of value, then reduce it to find min.
  var minimun = keys.map((key) => answer[key]).reduce((min, item) => {
    return (item.active && item.selectOrder < min.selectOrder) ? item : min;
  }, {active: true, selectOrder: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER});

  // Set min to selected.
  minimun.selected = true;
  return answer;
};
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fezuganoja/1/edit?js,console)

2. It's not `JSON`, it's just a plain `Object` with some key-value mappings, and we use it as a `Map`. It may be easier to apply above logic if the input is an array like:

```
var settings = [
  {
    name: 'tab1',
    active: true,
    selectOrder: 1,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: 'tab2',
    active: true,
    selectOrder: 2,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: 'tab3',
    active: false,
    selectOrder: 0,
    selected: false
  }
];
```

As vanilla javascript supports reduce/map on `array`. However, as many libs like [lodash](https://lodash.com/), [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) just make reduce/map available on objects. You can 
just choose the one the suits your needs most (As there's many lib like  that makes you able to map/reduce through objects).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. I think that I'll stick to the vanilla js for now.

Answer (score 2):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com), you can write the following:

```
import { chain, transform, extend } from 'lodash';

transformObj = (obj) => chain(settings)
  .map((obj, key)=> ({ key, obj }))
  .select(({ obj: { active }})=> active)
  .min(({ obj: { selectOrder }})=> selectOrder)
  .thru(({ key })=> transform(settings, (memo, val, _key) => {
      memo[_key] = extend({}, val, {
        selected: (_key == key)
      })
    }, {})
  )
  .value()
```

---

```
> transformObj(settings)
{ tab1: { active: true, selectOrder: 1, selected: true },
  tab2: { active: true, selectOrder: 2, selected: false },
  tab3: { active: false, selectOrder: 0, selected: false } }
```

The above assumes availability of ES6 [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and argument [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Otherwise you can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=import%20%7B%20chain%2C%20transform%2C%20extend%20%7D%20from%20%27lodash%27%3B%0A%0AtransformObj%20%3D%20%28obj%29%20%3D%3E%20chain%28settings%29%0A%20%20.map%28%28obj%2C%20key%29%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20key%2C%20obj%20%7D%29%29%0A%20%20.select%28%28%7B%20obj%3A%20%7B%20active%20%7D%7D%29%3D%3E%20active%29%0A%20%20.min%28%28%7B%20obj%3A%20%7B%20selectOrder%20%7D%7D%29%3D%3E%20selectOrder%29%0A%20%20.thru%28%28%7B%20key%20%7D%29%3D%3E%20transform%28settings%2C%20%28memo%2C%20val%2C%20_key%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20memo%5B_key%5D%20%3D%20extend%28%7B%7D%2C%20val%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selected%3A%20%28_key%20%3D%3D%20key%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%20%20.value%28%29%0A).

This is more functional because `transformObj` is referentially transparent & does not mutate its arguments.

Comment: Cool. I was looking for something like this. The problem is that it looks much more complicated and inefficient than the "regular" solution. In addition, I have to add another library to my page. Is it the better solution?

Comment: Better is subjective to opinion. As far as complicated is concerned, I have found a chain of transformations to be easier to decipher and debug in case of more complex transformations - of course given that the use case is somewhat simple, it may be an overkill. Yes you do have to add a library but lodash is something I have found to be invaluable and after a while the provided set of higher order functions become second nature. If your particularly conscious about the added bloat, you can pick and choose the specific functions you need in a custom build. https://lodash.com/custom-builds

Comment: As far as inefficiency is concerned - an iterative solution will certainly be more efficient, but in complex use cases efficient immutable data structures can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
tmp = 0;
_tab = false;
for ( tab in settings ){
    if((settings[tab].active)){
        if(!tmp){
            tmp = settings[tab].selectOrder;
            _tab  = tab;
        }else if(settings[tab].selectOrder < tmp){
            _tab = tab;
        }
    };
}
settings[_tab].selected = true;
```

Comment: How is this more "functional" approach? This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (looping over the object) and saving variables with state

Comment: In your code you use 2 loops , i'm trying to reduce looping

Comment: The second loop was for updating the false values. I can use only one, this wasn't my problem... I was looking for "fuctional" approach. Thanks anyway!